# Inserir registros SQL Server via ftp file.txt

Tags: sql-server, ftp

Tenho a seguinte estrutura em um arquivo .txt de um servidor FTP:

```
CodigoPedido: 120952

DataPedido: 2014-03-11-10:19

LocalVenda: MERCADO LIVRE

Status: A ENVIAR

Parceiro: 0

IdCliente: 103002

NomeCliente: Juliano Ramires Garcia | JRAMIRES GARCIA
```

Existe alguma forma de automatizar o processo para o SQL Server conectar no FTP, carregar o arquivo, fazer um parseamento, inserir o registro e deletar o arquivo do FTP?

Comment: Queres mesmo fazer isso? Estas' a abrir uma porta que te podera' trazer graves problemas de seguranca.

Comment: Não vejo falha de segurança nisso. Qual seria?

Comment: Simples imagina que eu envio um ficheiro para esse ftp com um comando como por exemplo drop database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Recomendação inicial

Antes de mais nada, eu recomendaria criar um processo a parte para fazer isso.

Poderia ser um script em ShellScript, Python, PHP ou uma linguagem similar executado de forma agendada pelo `cron` (Linux) ou Agendador de Tarefas (Windows).

Esse script seria responsável por recuperar o arquivo, ler os dados, validar e então enviar um comando ao SQL, sendo este passivo nessa história.

## Solução com T-SQL

### Habilitar execução de comandos do sistema

Entretanto, a linguagem T-SQL (*Transact-SQL*) possui comandos que possibilitam a interação com o ambiente.

O primeiro passo é habilitar o comando [`xp_cmdshell`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx). Para isso, siga os passos descritos na [documentação oficial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx):

```sql
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

### Chamar o FTP

Então, no seu script SQL, você pode recuperar o arquivo remoto invocando o utilitário `ftp` do Windows. O parâmetro `-s` permite especificar um arquivo com os comandos FTP. Veja [este exemplo](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aeda8ca6-1f13-443f-9558-957b85c5e616/how-to-connect-ftp-server-using-tsql):

```sql
Set @cmd = 'ftp -s:"C:\comandos.txt" 127.0.0.0'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

No exemplo acima, o arquivo `comandos.txt` teria os comandos FTP a serem executados.

Mas o importante aqui é que com a possibilidade de executar um programa qualquer, você pode virtualmente fazer o que quiser. Pode chamar um programa em Java ou um script qualquer.

### Lendo o arquivo em uma variável

Em seguida, para ler o arquivo, você pode usar o comando [OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx). Tem um exemplo no link da documentação que permite ler o arquivo em formato binário. Modificando o formato para caracteres, você pode colocar numa variável qualquer. Use `SINGLE_CLOB` se o conteúdo do arquivo for codificado em ASCII ou `SINGLE_NCLOB` se for Unicode. Exemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @conteudo NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT @conteudo = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\dados.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Document;
```

### Fazendo o "parseamento"

A última etapa seria fazer o *parse*. Na verdade, o ideal é já gravar o arquivo num formato adequado, separado por vírgulas, com aspas e assim por diante. Tente não deixar essa carga para o SQL Server porque ele não foi feito para isso.

Não vou desenvolver a solução porque seria algo muito específico e não vale a pena. Porém, vou deixar alguns comandos que podem ajudar caso você precise.

Existem várias [funções de manipulação de strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx):

1. Com o `CHARINDEX` e `PATINDEX` você consegue encontrar a posição dos *labels*.
2. Então, com o `SUBSTRING` dá pra pegar o texto que fica na frente deles. Não é tão complicado, é mais questão de trabalho manual.

## Considerações finais

Embora seja possível fazer essa solução, existem formas melhores e mais flexíveis, como apresentadas no início da resposta.

### Segurança

Quanto à questão da segurança, isso pode ser um problema dependendo de onde fica o FTP. Se for um servidor interno da empresa com acesso apenas pelos administradores isso não seria tão ruim. Porém, se for um FTP externo pode ser uma grande falha. Primeiro, o FTP não é um protocolo seguro, os dados trafegam em texto puro, por exemplo. Segundo, você estaria acrescentando um outro ponto de invasão. Se um hacker comprometer o servidor de FTP, ele pode injetar comandos espúrios no arquivo text e conseguir executar algum comando no seu servidor de bancos de dados. O que seria o nome de um cliente, pode ser um SQL Injection.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Desempenho

Outro fator que pode ser impactado é o desempenho do seu servidor de banco de dados. Dependendo de quantos arquivos forem lidos no dia, o fato do SQL ter que conectar ao FTP (que pode ser uma conexão lenta) e então fazer a interpretação do conteúdo, pode gerar uma carga adicional desnecessário ao servidor.

Sinceramente eu não sei como o SQL Server trata a questão de *threads* e *processos*, mas com certeza uma delas ficaria bloqueada aguardando a resposta do comando `ftp`, por exemplo.

Comment: A questão do formato do arquivo não tem como alterar, pois já é a saída de um outro software, estou fazendo adaptação. E não há possíbilidade de deixar via cron, já havia pensado nessa alternativa. O que me resta é deixar por cargo do próprio MSSQL. Já achei um script que baixa os arquivos do ftp necessários e armazena em uma pasta temp, a questão é abrir, parsear e inserir. Na questão de carga excessiva não sera um problema, pois são poucos os dados inseridos. Na questão de segurança realmente é um fator delicado, porém, não foi uma decisão minha esse método...